Customizing Chapter Style (\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}) for different chapter or sections
Im trying to adapt a modification of the chapter style but I found some minor problems that Im not able to solve. Im working from the code found in the topic: How can I get a color gradient of the rectangle on my chapter style in fncychap? (\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap})?
I have a book document class with frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter.
In the frontmatter the code works perfect.In the mainmatter I find some minor problems when the chapter title is too long:

In the appendices, the code works also pretty well:

Even that in this case i get the following error:
<to be read again> 
                   A
l.97 \chapter{Recipes for biophysics}
                                     \label{A01_Recipes}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Because for this chapters I suppose that condition \thechapter>0 is not matched as the value should be zero.
The real problem comes when I get to the bibliography and last two sections (all contained in the backmatter), in this case, they appear with the numeration of the last appendix.

I tried to add some new logic but is the first time that I code Latex at this depth and im completely lost. Also I tried to condition the code to the parts of the book (mainmatter, backmattter etc) but dindt find a way. All IA generated code that I tried was dump btw.
Thanks in advance!

Note you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that others can copy and work directly.
